# How to update autocomplete combobox suggestion list with info from the database (TornadoFX)?

Tags: combobox, autocomplete, tornadofx

I have an auto complete combobox that works well but suggestion list does not update after `runAsync` operation is completed.

```
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty
import javafx.collections.ObservableList
import tornadofx.*

class TestBox : View("My View") {

var treatment = SimpleObjectProperty<String>()
var treatmentList = SimpleObjectProperty<ObservableList<String>>()
override val root = borderpane {
    center {
        form {
            fieldset {
                field("Fruit") {
                    combobox(treatment, treatmentList.value) {
                        makeAutocompletable()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
init {
    runAsync {
        listOf("Rice", "beans", "Yams").observable()
    } ui {
        treatmentList.set(it)
    }
}
}
```

What am I missing out? Thanks.

Comment: Please make your sample runnable, and remove dependencies on third party libs and external dependencies :)

Comment: I have edited the code. Now it is runnable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the `ObservableList`. You are changing the contents of the property containing the list. The combobox never knows about the `treatmentList` property, therefore it cannot observe on it.
Try making `treatmentList` an `ObservableList<String>`. Then, you can do `treatmentList.setAll(it)` in `runAsync`s `ui` block.

```
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty
import tornadofx.*

class TestBox : View("My View") {
    var treatment = SimpleObjectProperty<String>()
    var treatmentList = mutableListOf<String>().observable()
    override val root = borderpane {
        center {
            form {
                fieldset {
                    field("Fruit") {
                        combobox(treatment, treatmentList) {
                            makeAutocompletable()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    init {
        runAsync {
            listOf("Rice", "beans", "Yams")
        } ui {
            treatmentList.setAll(it)
        }
    }
}
```